# Okta + Custom Login Page + react native

Tags: react-native, okta, okta-api

I have developed a react native app and integrated OKTA with it . at present if the users opens the app then he will redirect to OKTA login page to enter his/her details and sign in and he will redirect again to native app. But my client requirement is the user should enter details in native login page so that internally making use of OKTA API's he should validate and move further into app so that the user will not redirect any other OKTA pages.
can any one please help me out. How to do it in react native. I tried searching for it but could not get a clarity how to start.
My search result : we can do it using OKTA primary authentication API but how to implement it in react native code wise.

Comment: At the moment we don't have an example of doing a primary authentication flow with react native, just the redirect flow which you can look at here: https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react-native/

Comment: Okay. But above link specifies that the user will redirect to login page of okta and then again to app.

Comment: Not only by primary authentication can we do it using any okta-sigin widget and authenticate the user in app itself.